# Best way to determine Server Product version and execute SQL accordingly?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This is a two-pronged question:
Scenario:

I have a script to query MSDB and get me details of job schedules. Obviously, the tables differ from SQL 2000 to SQL 2005. Hence, I want to check the version running on the box and query accordingly. Now the questions:

Question 1:

This is what I am doing.

```
IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='8'
BEGIN
PRINT 'SQL 2000'--Actual Code Goes Here
END
IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='9'
BEGIN
PRINT 'SQL 2005'--Actual Code Goes Here
END
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Question 2:

Though the above script runs fine on both 2000 and 2005 boxes, when I replace the "Print.." statements with my actual code, it runs fine on a 2000 box, but when executed on a 2005 box,tries to run the code block meant for 2000 and returns errors.

Here is the actual code:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
--Check SQL Server Version
IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='9'
BEGIN
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
,sysjobs.name
,dbo.udf_schedule_description(dbo.sysschedules.freq_type, dbo.sysschedules.freq_interval,  
dbo.sysschedules.freq_subday_type, dbo.sysschedules.freq_subday_interval, dbo.sysschedules.freq_relative_interval,  
dbo.sysschedules.freq_recurrence_factor, dbo.sysschedules.active_start_date, dbo.sysschedules.active_end_date,  
dbo.sysschedules.active_start_time, dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time) AS [Schedule Description]
, CONVERT(CHAR(8), CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END, 108) AS Start_Time,
       CONVERT(CHAR(8), CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END, 108) AS End_Time
,CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 1
                         THEN CAST('00:00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1)AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 2
                         THEN CAST('00:00:' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 2)AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END AS VARCHAR(8))  AS LastRunDuration
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs INNER JOIN
msdb.dbo.syscategories ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.category_id = msdb.dbo.syscategories.category_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
msdb.dbo.sysoperators ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.notify_page_operator_id = msdb.dbo.sysoperators.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.job_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules ON msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id LEFT OUTER JOIN
msdb.dbo.sysschedules ON msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.schedule_id = msdb.dbo.sysschedules.schedule_id
WHERE sysjobs.enabled = 1 AND msdb.dbo.sysschedules.Active_Start_Time IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Start_time,sysjobs.name
END

IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='8'
BEGIN
SELECT @@SERVERNAME
,sysjobs.name
,dbo.udf_schedule_description(sysjobschedules.freq_type, sysjobschedules.freq_interval,  
sysjobschedules.freq_subday_type, sysjobschedules.freq_subday_interval, sysjobschedules.freq_relative_interval,  
sysjobschedules.freq_recurrence_factor, sysjobschedules.active_start_date, sysjobschedules.active_end_date,  
sysjobschedules.active_start_time, sysjobschedules.active_end_time) AS [Schedule Description]
, CONVERT(CHAR(8), CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.Active_Start_Time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END, 108) AS Start_Time,
       CONVERT(CHAR(8), CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobschedules.active_end_time AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END, 108) AS End_Time
,CAST(CASE WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 1
                         THEN CAST('00:00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1)AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 2
                         THEN CAST('00:00:' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 2)AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 3
                         THEN CAST('00:0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 4
                         THEN CAST('00:' 
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          1, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN LEN(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration) = 5
                         THEN CAST('0' + LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 1) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          2, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          4, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                         WHEN msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration = 0
                         THEN '00:00:00'
                         ELSE CAST(LEFT(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          3, 2) + ':'
                              + SUBSTRING(CAST(msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                                          5, 2) AS VARCHAR(8))
                    END AS VARCHAR(8))  AS LastRunDuration
FROM sysjobs LEFT OUTER JOIN 
msdb.dbo.sysjobservers ON msdb.dbo.sysjobs.job_id = msdb.dbo.sysjobservers.job_id INNER JOIN
sysjobschedules ON sysjobs.job_id = sysjobschedules.job_id 
WHERE sysjobs.enabled = 1
ORDER BY Start_time,sysjobs.name
END
```

This script requires a udf in MSDB. Here is the code for the function:

```
USE [msdb]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_schedule_description] (@freq_type INT ,
 @freq_interval INT ,
 @freq_subday_type INT ,
 @freq_subday_interval INT ,
 @freq_relative_interval INT ,
 @freq_recurrence_factor INT ,
 @active_start_date INT ,
 @active_end_date INT,
 @active_start_time INT ,
 @active_end_time INT ) 
RETURNS NVARCHAR(255) AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @schedule_description NVARCHAR(255)
DECLARE @loop INT
DECLARE @idle_cpu_percent INT
DECLARE @idle_cpu_duration INT

IF (@freq_type = 0x1) -- OneTime
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = N'Once on ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @active_start_date) + N' at ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, cast((@active_start_time / 10000) as varchar(10)) + ':' + right('00' + cast((@active_start_time % 10000) / 100 as varchar(10)),2))
 RETURN @schedule_description
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x4) -- Daily
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = N'Every day '
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x8) -- Weekly
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = N'Every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_recurrence_factor) + N' week(s) on '
 SELECT @loop = 1
 WHILE (@loop <= 7)
 BEGIN
 IF (@freq_interval & POWER(2, @loop - 1) = POWER(2, @loop - 1))
 SELECT @schedule_description = @schedule_description + DATENAME(dw, N'1996120' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @loop)) + N', '
 SELECT @loop = @loop + 1
 END
 IF (RIGHT(@schedule_description, 2) = N', ')
 SELECT @schedule_description = SUBSTRING(@schedule_description, 1, (DATALENGTH(@schedule_description) / 2) - 2) + N' '
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x10) -- Monthly
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = N'Every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_recurrence_factor) + N' months(s) on day ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_interval) + N' of that month '
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x20) -- Monthly Relative
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = N'Every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_recurrence_factor) + N' months(s) on the '
 SELECT @schedule_description = @schedule_description +
 CASE @freq_relative_interval
 WHEN 0x01 THEN N'first '
 WHEN 0x02 THEN N'second '
 WHEN 0x04 THEN N'third '
 WHEN 0x08 THEN N'fourth '
 WHEN 0x10 THEN N'last '
 END +
 CASE
 WHEN (@freq_interval > 00)
 AND (@freq_interval < 08) THEN DATENAME(dw, N'1996120' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_interval))
 WHEN (@freq_interval = 08) THEN N'day'
 WHEN (@freq_interval = 09) THEN N'week day'
 WHEN (@freq_interval = 10) THEN N'weekend day'
 END + N' of that month '
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x40) -- AutoStart
 BEGIN
 SELECT @schedule_description = FORMATMESSAGE(14579)
 RETURN @schedule_description
 END
IF (@freq_type = 0x80) -- OnIdle
 BEGIN
 EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
 N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent',
 N'IdleCPUPercent',
 @idle_cpu_percent OUTPUT,
 N'no_output'
 EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_instance_regread N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
 N'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\SQLServerAgent',
 N'IdleCPUDuration',
 @idle_cpu_duration OUTPUT,
 N'no_output'
 SELECT @schedule_description = FORMATMESSAGE(14578, ISNULL(@idle_cpu_percent, 10), ISNULL(@idle_cpu_duration, 600))
 RETURN @schedule_description
 END
-- Subday stuff
 SELECT @schedule_description = @schedule_description +
 CASE @freq_subday_type
 WHEN 0x1 THEN N'at ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, cast(
 CASE WHEN LEN(cast((@active_start_time / 10000)as varchar(10)))=1
     THEN  '0'+cast((@active_start_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     ELSE cast((@active_start_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     END    
as varchar(10)) + ':' + right('00' + cast((@active_start_time % 10000) / 100 as varchar(10)),2))
 WHEN 0x2 THEN N'every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_subday_interval) + N' second(s)'
 WHEN 0x4 THEN N'every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_subday_interval) + N' minute(s)'
 WHEN 0x8 THEN N'every ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @freq_subday_interval) + N' hour(s)'
 END
 IF (@freq_subday_type IN (0x2, 0x4, 0x8))
 SELECT @schedule_description = @schedule_description + N' between ' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, cast(
CASE WHEN LEN(cast((@active_start_time / 10000)as varchar(10)))=1
     THEN  '0'+cast((@active_start_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     ELSE cast((@active_start_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     END    
as varchar(10)) + ':' + right('00' + cast((@active_start_time % 10000) / 100 as varchar(10)),2) ) 
+ N' and ' +
CONVERT(NVARCHAR, cast(
 CASE WHEN LEN(cast((@active_end_time / 10000)as varchar(10)))=1
     THEN  '0'+cast((@active_end_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     ELSE cast((@active_end_time / 10000) as varchar(10))
     END    
as varchar(10)) + ':' + right('00' + cast((@active_end_time % 10000) / 100 as varchar(10)),2) )


RETURN @schedule_description
END
```

I have got this far and have spent too much time trying to find out what the problem is. Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the errors are compile time (I ran on 2005):

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 106
Invalid column name 'freq_type'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 106
Invalid column name 'freq_interval'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 107
Invalid column name 'freq_subday_type'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 107
Invalid column name 'freq_subday_interval'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 107
Invalid column name 'freq_relative_interval'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 108
Invalid column name 'freq_recurrence_factor'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 108
Invalid column name 'active_start_date'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 108
Invalid column name 'active_end_date'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 109
Invalid column name 'active_start_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 109
Invalid column name 'active_end_time'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 110
```

I added PRINTs and they never appear.

your code has problems because the column names are not compatible with the database you are running.  SQL Server 2005 does not have a "sysjobschedules.freq_type" column.

Make a stored procedure XYZ, put the 2000 version in the 2000 database, put the same XYZ procedure on the 2005 machine and put the 2005 version in it.  No IF necessary...

**EDIT**

run this code:

```
PRINT 'Works'
```

now run this code

```
PRINT 'will not see this'
error
```

try this:

```
PRINT 'will not see this'
SELECT xyz from sysjobschedules
```

now try running this, but only highlight the PRINT line:

```
PRINT 'you can see this'  --only select this line of code and run it
SELECT xyz from sysjobschedules
```

see how compile errors prevent anything from running

**EDIT**

you might try something like this...

```
DECLARE @Query varchar(max)

IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='8'
BEGIN
    SET @Query=......
END
IF LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') As Varchar),1)='9'
BEGIN
    SET @Query=......
END

EXEC (@Query)
```

Comment: Try running just the block where the IF..productversion return '9' on a SQL 2005 box. It returns correct result sets. I need to run this on multiple boxes to generate reports and need to decide the Product Version at runtime. Hence the IF.. construct

Comment: install the 2000 version on the 2000 boxes, and the 2005 version on the 2005 boxes, use the same stored procedure name.  when you highlight only part of the code and run it, it only complies that part of which the invalid columns are not included and it works.

Comment: The problem is that I have to query 127 boxes with a mix on 2000 and 2005 and do not really want to be creating SPs on all those boxes. I agree with your answer of Compile time issues, but how come it runs fine on a 2000 box? Is there a better way other than creating SPs, to query and report at run time?

Comment: Thanks KM. I did exactly what you recommended in your last edit and it works.

Comment: @Raj, I'm glad it works for you, someone still gave me a downvote ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The original question is only specific to 2000,2005 but here's some code that should work on 2000, 2005, 2008 and onwards

```
DECLARE @ver NVARCHAR(128)
DECLARE @majorVersion int
SET @ver = CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productversion') AS NVARCHAR)
SET @ver = SUBSTRING(@ver,1,CHARINDEX('.',@ver)-1)
SET @majorVersion  = CAST(@ver AS INT)
IF @majorVersion < 11
    PRINT 'Plesae Upgrade'
ELSE
    PRINT @majorVersion
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on 2008 and it ran fine. are you in the msdb database when running it?

to get the version you can also do this

```
SELECT 
PARSENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion')),4) 
 AS SqlServerVersion
```

Comment: Yes I am. doesn't really matter as I have a USE MSDB statement.

Comment: And come to think of it, shouldn't the SQL Version check return 10 on SQL 2008? I have not handled that and the code should not ideally return any results on 2008!!!

Answer (score 0):

--I found it easier this way to code for service pack features for multiple SQL versions.

For example, say I want all the new performance counters and know they were released on a particular service pack on multiple SQL versions. So if I code for greater than SQL Server 12 SP3, SQL 2014 SP2, AND SQL 2016 or better I would do this.

```
DECLARE @sql_version INT = CONVERT(INT,LEFT(REPLACE(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS CHAR(15)),'.',''),7))

SELECT 
CASE
    WHEN
        (@sql_version >= 1106020 AND @sql_version < 1200000) OR
        (@sql_version >= 1205000 AND @sql_version < 1300000) OR
        @sql_version >= 1301601
    THEN
        'Execute code block'
    ELSE
        'Execute code block'
    END
```

or shorthand like this...

```
 SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN
            (@sql_version BETWEEN 1106020 AND 1200000) OR
            (@sql_version BETWEEN 1205000 AND 1300000) OR
            @sql_version >= 1301601
        THEN
            'Execute code block'
        ELSE
            'Execute code block'
        END
```

Easy, eh?